# Unable to cast UIKit.UIView to type UIKit.UILabel?

Tags: ios, xamarin

In my project I am trying to get a reference to a label within a view. The view has 2 items in it both of which are UILabels.

```
var headerViews = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib(nibName,this,null);
// Only 1 view in the XIB as shown in the image below.
UIView headerView = headerViews.GetItem<UIView>(0);
UILabel nameLabel = (UILabel)headerView.ViewWithTag(1);
```

This is throwing the runtime error that it cannot cast the view to a label. Why not? This cast is valid in Objective-C and Swift.

This is what headerView looks like:

[image: The Parent View]

Comment: What code do you use to load the XIB? And do you get a compile time error or a runtime error?

Comment: @Glorfindel XIB loading code added. This is a run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to work with a more safe approach.

Create a UIView subclass, e.g. MyDialogView, in your XIB designer set this class to the main View and add Outlets for each control. 
Then add a method that you can pass a model class or values you want to update the View with.
In your code you can work using your MyDialogView class and invoke the method to update the view with data.

This way you don't need to work with casting and tags.

**[EDIT]** Code Example.

Create a class and derive from UIView, add the Register attribute to make it visible in XCode. It should be like the below.

```
    [Register("MyCustomView")]
    public partial class MyCustomView : UIView
    {
        CGSize _intrinsicContentSize;

        public UIView View { get; set; }

        public string Text { 
            get { return myLabel.Text; }
            set { myLabel.Text = value; }
        }

        public MyCustomView ()
        {
            SetupView ();
        }

        public MyCustomView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            SetupView ();
        }

        private UIView LoadViewFromXib()
        {
            NSBundle bundle = NSBundle.FromClass (this.Class);
            UINib nib = UINib.FromName ("MyCustomView", bundle);
            return nib.Instantiate (this, null)[0] as UIView;
        }

        private void SetupView()
        {
            this.View = LoadViewFromXib ();
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
            this.Bounds = this.View.Bounds;
            _intrinsicContentSize = this.Bounds.Size;
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            AddSubview (this.View);
        }

        public override CGSize IntrinsicContentSize {
            get {
                return _intrinsicContentSize;
            }
        }
    }
```

In your XIB file don't set the View's class to MyCustomView but the File's Owner to MyCustomView.

In your ViewController somewhere, e.g. ViewDidLoad add the following.

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            MyCustomView customView = new MyCustomView ();
            customView.Text = "Test Label Text";

            Add (customView);
        }
```

Run and you should see the update label in your custom view.

Comment: That was my first option, but I can't seem to make that work in Xamarin either.

Comment: Works for me. Xamarin is no different from iOS, all the bindings and culture is still there. Unfortunately I don't have access right now to code, I will update later today with a sample.

Comment: My problem was trying to create the outlets. The assistant editor doesn't show anything even after setting the view's class. I also ran into issues when trying to cast to a custom UIView subclass.

Comment: Tried adding the Register command to the class in Xamarin. Xcode still doesn't seem to know about it. When I show the assistant editor it shows the NSObject class instead of mine.